# Adding values in a row to the previous one in R

Tags: r, row

I would like to perform a simple operation in R that is easily done in excel:

I have a col consisting of 5045 entries called K. I would like to create a second col L where the first value is L1=100+K[1] the second is L2=L1+K[2], the third is L3=L2+K[3] and so on.

Is there a simple way to do this in R? in Excel one just has to pull down the col.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like

```
L <- 100 + cumsum(K)
```

Comment: +1 Neat - I had missed that when I started writing my Answer, only for it to dawn on me when I was about finished.

Comment: +1 I had a hard time finding a vectorized solution and fell back to using a `for` loop. The timings in my answer show that this is terribly slow in comparison to using `cumsum`.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use `cumsum()` and cheat a little. For example, given `K`:

```
K <- 1:10
```

and to keep things simple I am adding `1` (not `100`) to `K[1]`, we want to produce:

```
> 1 + K[1]
[1] 2
> (1 + K[1]) + K[2]
[1] 4
> ((1 + K[1]) + K[2]) + K[3]
[1] 7
....
```

This is a cumulative sum. We need to cheat a little with the constant you want to add to the first element as we only want that to affect that first element, not be added to each element. Hence this is **wrong**

```
> L <- cumsum(1 + K) 
> L
 [1]  2  5  9 14 20 27 35 44 54 65
```

What we actually want is:

```
> L <- cumsum(c(1, K))[-1]
> L
 [1]  2  4  7 11 16 22 29 37 46 56
```

Wherein we concatenate the constant to the vector `K` as the first element and apply `cumsum()` to that, but drop the first element of the output from `cumsum()`.

This can of course be done in a slightly simpler fashion:

```
> L <- 1 + cumsum(K)
> L
 [1]  2  4  7 11 16 22 29 37 46 56
```

i.e. compute the `cumusum()` and *then* add on the constant (which I now see is what @gd047 has suggested in their Answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The following shows a `for` loop based solution. This is probably not what you want in terms of speed, where vectorized functions like `cumsum` are much faster.

```
a = 1:10
b = vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(a))
b[1] = 1 + a[1]

for(idx in 2:length(a)) {
  b[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx - 1]
}
```

Some timings:

```
require(rbenchmark)

for_loop_solution = function(a) {
    b = vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(a))
    b[1] = 1 + a[1]

    for(idx in 2:length(a)) {
      b[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx - 1]
    } 
    return(invisible(b))
}

cumsum_solution = function(a) {
   return(1 + cumsum(a))
}

sample_data = 1:10e3
benchmark(for_loop_solution(sample_data), 
          cumsum_solution(sample_data), 
          replications = 100)
                            test replications elapsed relative user.self
2   cumsum_solution(sample_data)          100   0.013    1.000     0.011
1 for_loop_solution(sample_data)          100   3.647  280.538     3.415
  sys.self user.child sys.child
2    0.002          0         0
1    0.006          0         0
```

which shows that using `cumsum` is a few hundred times faster than using an explicit for loop. This effect is going to be even more pronounced when the length of `sample_data` grows.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by Paul Hiemstra the builtin function `cumsum()` is fast.
But the for loop solution can be speeded up by using the compiler package.

```
library(compiler)
fls_compiled <- cmpfun(for_loop_solution)
```

Then using the same data let's run  `benchmark` as follows

```
benchmark(for_loop_solution(sample_data), 
          cumsum_solution(sample_data),
          fls_compiled(sample_data), 
          replications = 100)
                            test replications elapsed relative user.self
2   cumsum_solution(sample_data)          100   0.013    1.000     0.013
3      fls_compiled(sample_data)          100   0.726   55.846     0.717
1 for_loop_solution(sample_data)          100   4.417  339.769     3.723
  sys.self user.child sys.child
2    0.000          0         0
3    0.006          0         0
1    0.031          0         0
```

So use builtin functions wherever possible.
And if there is no builtin, try the compiler package. It often delivers faster code.